# Code serializing deserializing from Clojure

Tags: clojure, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am follwing the example here http://patternhatch.com/2013/06/12/messaging-using-clojure-and-zeromq/

I have verified that I can serialize MarketData and have built the protobuf for it.

Instead of using chesire serialization I decided to try my new learned protobuf serialization knowledge. When I modified the functions in that example into their gpb versions, when I run

```
(future-call market-data-publisher-gpb)
```

It seems ok. However, when I run the client

```
(get-market-data-gpb 100)
```

Nothing happens. I have two questions:

1) Is there some sort of graphical or otherwise debugger for Clojure?
2) If someone can point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong on my modfied example that would also be helpful.

I seem to remember that over ZMQ with a [protobuf] binary data payload required a different set of calls?

```
(ns clj-zmq.core
  (:import [org.jeromq ZMQ])
)

(use 'flatland.protobuf.core)

(import com.example.Example$MarketData)
(def MarketData (protodef Example$MarketData))


(def ctx (ZMQ/context 1))

(defn market-data-publisher-gpb
[]
  (let [s (.socket ctx ZMQ/PUB)
        market-data-event (fn []
                            {:symbol (rand-nth ["CAT" "UTX"])
                             :size (rand-int 1000)
                             :price (format "%.2f" (rand 50.0))})]
    (.bind s "tcp://127.0.0.1:6666")
    (while :true
      (.send s ( protobuf-dump(market-data-event))))))

; Client
(defn get-market-data-gpb
  [num-events]
  (let [s (.socket ctx ZMQ/SUB)]
    (.subscribe s "")
    (.connect s "tcp://127.0.0.1:6666")
    (dotimes [_ num-events]
      (println (protobuf-load MarketData (.recv s))))
    (.close s)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Eclipse Counterclockwise and IntelliJ Cursive have Clojure debug support.

Also, your address looks bad - should be "tcp://127.0.0.1:6666".

Comment: Thanks I will look into those. I did have that bug I corrected it (and modified the post above to reflect it) the program still just sits there and does nothing.

Comment: Still not sure why this code does not work. How would I get the size of the message in bytes that protobuf-dump creates, then prepend to that the size in bytes?

Comment: I am beginning to believe that jeromq is not strong enough to deal with binary messages.